# If A is diagonalizable find P sym + pos-def so AP is symmetric

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Trying to figure out a proof for this fact:

If $A$ is a square matrix over the real numbers, diagonalizable with real eigenvalues, then there exists $P$ a square matrix of the same size such that $P$ is symmetric and positive definite, and $AP$ is symmetric. (As mentioned in a comment, AP must be real, symmetric and Hermitian are synonymous.)

This is needed to transform a PDE into a form where the norm associated with the bilinear form $AP$ is equivalent to the standard inner product norm.

Thanks, and many apologies if this is a repeat question.

PSedit:
You can make some headway if you suppose that A has orthogonal eigenvectors, as then you can write $A = PDP^{-1}$ for diagonal $D$, so $AP = PD$, and if $P$ is symmetric, so is $PD = AP$. We also know that $P$ is symmetric, but I'm not sure (and not overly hopeful) that $P$ must be positive definite in this case.

Comment: Ah--I think you're right. A would always be real, so AP would be real as well. (If not, I think Hermitian would be the right quality.) I'll edit--thanks!

Comment: That absolutely works--thanks!

Comment: Submit as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: Done. Thanks......

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $A=MDM^{-1}$ be a diagonalisation. Then $P=MM^T$ is positive definite (because $M$ is invertible) and $AP=MDM^T$ is symmetric.